# Not able to capture the full address same as input value using v-model - Vue/Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, vuetify.js, google-places-autocomplete

I'm not able to capture the full address from the input tag which is filled through google autocomplete API using Vuetify and also filled address is different than the `formatted_address`.

For instance, if I type the address `Statue of Liberty National Monument, New York, NY, USA` in the input tag, google formatted_address is coming as this one `New York, NY 10004, USA` which is not matching with the input. So I tried using `v-model` binding to get the input value. However, it is not giving the full address instead it returns this `statue`

Here is the snippet code:

```
 <v-text-field ref="autocomplete" v-model="address" id="autocomplete-address" autocomplete="off" solo outlined flat hide-details="auto" class="solo-cust mb-2"></v-text-field>
```

And JS code:

```
const App = {
  template: "#app-template",
  data: () => ({
    autocomplete: null,
    address: null,
    fullAddress: null
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.init();
  },
  methods: {
    async init() {
      const element = document.getElementById("autocomplete-address");
      this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element);
      this.autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", this.update);
    },
    async update() {
      const place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
      const address = place.address_components;
      this.fullAddress = place.formatted_address;
      this.form.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
      this.form.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
    }
  }
};

new Vue({
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Can anyone suggest to me how do I capture the full address same as the input value which is this `Statue of Liberty National Monument, New York, NY, USA`?

[Please check this working code pen here](https://codepen.io/harshitha-naidu/pen/abWNoBB?editors=1010)

Comment: can you try await this.autocomplete??

Comment: @HenriqueVanKlaveren How does `await` work for `this.autocomplete` as it's not a function and it throws this  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment `

Comment: The `formatted_address` as its name says contains the address. *Statue of Liberty National Monument* is not part of the address. It's the place name. A simple console log of your `place` variable is very likely to provide you with the answer.

Comment: And as to why you can't get the input value, if you look at it, you will see that the input value always holds what you typed in the field and **not** the API result string you selected (and which is somehow displayed by the widget).

Comment: @MrUpsidown It is not giving the input value with v-model, I tried checking multiple times. If you don't mind could you please check the codepen which I attached to the question?

Comment: It does. Read my comment again. The input value is what you typed in.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I've read your comments. Please do check this screenshot of what I meant? https://prnt.sc/197n87o

Comment: I don't know how else I can say it. If you type in "sta" the input value will be "sta". If you type "statue" the input value will be "statue".

Comment: And in any case, the `this.autocomplete.getPlace();` will return **all** what you need. You just need to grab the place name and formatted address and "rebuild" the selected place text.

Comment: @MrUpsidown `this.autocomplete.getPlace();` even I loop through the address_components and formatted_address I'm not able to get the full address that input has https://prnt.sc/197yijh

Comment: Right, yes, the only difference is that you will get "United States" or "US" instead of USA. If you are unhappy with that, open a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/components/188872).